# Facebook Insights reliable way of getting the last update?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

Today is 23 gen 2012. I'm querying Facebook Insights with FQL using PHP SDK. The metrics show different delay in insights updates:

- `page_friends_of_fans metric`: **available for 20** gen 2012 and before, not available for 21 gen 2012
- `page_fans`:  **available for 21** gen 2012 and before, not for 22 gen 2012

*First date of availability for both is then: 20 gen 2012.* Pattern could be today minus 3 days. **Since i have to specify end_date parameter, is there any reliable way of getting the last available date?**

Comment: I've just created a bug report on this : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164619063648278?browse=search_4f26cbfab62600058150653

Comment: fyi: Facebook is **removing** the **page_friends_of_fans** metric from the Insights API on July 10, 2013 according to their latest platform update: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/

Answer (score 0):

> The current answers do not contain enough detail.

This appears to be a reported bug that Facebook has **assigned** and given **high** priority to.   So the only reliable way it to wait for the bug fix to be deployed to production (or the beta site if you're so inclined in using it).

Here's the bug information.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164619063648278?browse=search_4f26cbfab62600058150653

> Insights API returns no results after january 24... We're january 30.
> It's not really the delays that is bothering us (even if shorter would
> be a lot better), it's just this delay changes over time. A few weeks
> ago we could retrieve data that would be 4 days old. Now it's 6 (or
> even more). It's thus becoming very difficult to update our apps as we
> have no idea when the new update will be provided.
>
> Can't Facebook fix a delay (say D+4) ?
>
> Status: Assigned
>
> Priority: High
>
> Updated: February 1 at 8:23pm

Comment: Steeve has posted comment with this link a week ago.

Comment: The first place anyone should look is in the bug reports to see if their issue is a bug.  Steeve must have done the same thing :)